# R spTransform projected point(s) not finite

Tags: r, geospatial, shapes, reprojection-error

I downloaded the TDWG level4 shape from http://www1.kew.org/gis/tdwg/index.html. This shape has a WGS84 projection. I need to reproject this layer to European LAEA or CRS("+init=epsg:3035").

I used the following code:

```
TDWG4 <- readOGR("D:/GIS/Administrative/world/TDWG/level4/level4.shp", layer="level4")
TDWG4.LAEA <- spTransform(TDWG4, CRS("+init=epsg:3035"))
```

and get the following error:

> Error in .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  : 
>     failure in Polygons 37 Polygon 1 points 
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  :
>     361 projected point(s) not finite

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sf` as this has largely superseded `rgdal/rgeos`:

```
# install.packages("sf")
library("sf")
tdwg4.laea = sf::read_sf("level4.shp")  # assumes in project root
tdwg4.laea = sf::st_transform(tdwg4.laea, 3035)
```

We now have to clip the area because the 3035 EPSG is only relevant for Europe:

```
install.packages("rmapshaper")
library("rmapshaper")
tdwg4.laea = rmapshaper::ms_clip(
  tdwg4.laea,
  bbox = c(2426378.0132, 1528101.2618, 6293974.6215, 5446513.5222))
```

Bounding box for EPSG 3035 is from: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-etrs-laea/

Now plot:

```
plot(tdwg4.laea)
```

[image: Plot of Europe]

Comment: Almost there. I tried to plot the transformed shape focussing on Europe using:

plot(TDWG4.LAEA['Level4_cod'], xlim=c(943611, 8500000), ylim=c(600000, 7800000))

But get the following error:

    Error in polypath(p_bind(L), border = border[i], lty = lty[i], lwd = lwd[i], : Invalid graphics path

Any suggestions?

Comment: @NielsRaes have you tried ggplot instead of base plot? `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`, `library("ggplot2")  # need dev version of ggplot2`, `ggplot(data = TDWG4.LAEA) + geom_sf()`?

Comment: while opening the ggplot2 installed using devtools I get this error: _Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 lazy-load database 'D:/R/library/ggplot2/R/ggplot2.rdb' is corrupt_. When using the regular ggplot2 library and `ggplot2::ggplot(data = TDWG4) + geom_sf()` I get the error: _Error in geom_sf() : could not find function "geom_sf"_. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @NielsRaes Sorry, my bad: I missed that you're only trying to plot Europe (the error is because the transformation has been applied to areas outside Europe so doesn't make sense). See edit

Comment: Thanks Phil, that did the job. Only dat --> tdwg.laea. Interesting libraries, never used those before.

Comment: @niels corrected. Please consider accepting the answer so others can see the question is solved.